# Treating missing values as really missing in Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, vowpalwabbit

Is there a way to correctly represent missing values in VW input format -- not to impute with the mean or median, not to set them to 0 or any other constant, but to treat them as really missing, so that SGD and FTRL-Proximal algorithms could exclude these coordinates from the gradient computation for a given example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VW expects sparse feature representation input format, see [VW wiki](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Input-format). So missing values are treated correctly. Simply, don't list the features whose values are missing.

Comment: As far as I know VW will consider unreported features as carrying a value of 0. I'm not sure why this is the right approach, when the unreported features carry numeric semantics in the domain. I'd actually think imputing with the median/mean/etc would make sense in many cases, but happy to learn if I'm wrong here.